# C++ Can an fstream object be set to automatically write a newline on each call to <<?

Tags: c++, newline, fstream

I've created an fstream object to write info to files.
I write strings to the new file like

```
fStreamObject << "New message.\n";
```

because I want each << to print a string to the next line.

I want to be able to set a property and make a call like

```
fstreamObject << "New message.";
```

which will write the string to the next line.

Are there flags/settings for fstream objects that allows this to be done?

I've seen the different file modes (i.e. ofstream::in, ofstream::out, etc.), but I couldn't find one that auto writes to a new line.  Also, I'm not looking to write my own solution.  I want to be able to use a built in feature.

Comment: Why don't you create a function that does that for you? Or maybe a class with overloaded operators so you can use it exactly like your normal stream, except it would put everything in a new line.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your question. But in what scenario are you needing this thing that you requested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no readily configurable capabilities of that sort within the *standard* streams.

You may have to subclass the stream type and fiddle with `operator<<` to get this to work the way you want, or do it with a helper function of some description:

```
fstreamObject << nl("New message.");
```

(but that's hardly easier than just having the `\n` in there (for a string, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "setting the stream". If we consider this to be fairly broad then the answer happens to be "yes"!

Here is how:

1. Create a stream buffer which inserts a newline every time it is flushed, i.e., when `sync()` is called. Otherwise it just forwards characters.
2. Change the file stream's stream buffer to use this stream buffer filtering to the file stream's stream buffer.
3. Set the flag `std::ios_base::unitbuf` which causes a flush after every [properly written] output operation.

Here are is the example code to do just that:

```
#include <iostream>

class newlinebuf
    : public std::streambuf {
    std::ostream*   stream;
    std::streambuf* sbuf;
    int overflow(int c) { return this->sbuf->sputc(c); }
    int sync() {
        return (this->sbuf->sputc('\n') == std::char_traits::eof() 
                || this->sbuf->pubsync() == -1)? -1: 0;
    }
public:
    newlinebuf(std::ostream& stream)
        : stream(&stream)
        , sbuf(stream.rdbuf(this)) {
        stream << std::unitbuf;
    }
    ~newlinebuf() { this->stream->rdbuf(this->sbuf); }
};

int main() {
    newlinebuf sbuf(std::cout);

    std::cout << "hello" << "world";
}
```

Although this approach work, I would recommend *against* using it! On problem is that all composite output operators, i.e., those using multiple output operators to do their work, will cause multiple newlines. I'm not aware of anything which can be done to prevent this behavior. There isn't anything in the standard library which enables just configuring the stream to do this: you'll need to insert the newline somehow.

Comment: Urgh, beat me by 3 minutes!

Comment: Your `sync` has potentially different return-value than the wrapped one. And it presumes that each creation of a `sentry` should add a newline, not every top-level use of `<<`. Which might be what the OP wants anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, the C++ streams do not allow that.
There is no way to decide where one insertion stops and the next starts.
For example for custom types, their stream-inserters are often implemented as calls to other stream-inserters and member-functions.

The only things you *can* do, is write your own class, which delegates to a stream of your choosing, and does that.
That's of strictly limited utiliy though.

```
struct alwaysenter {
     std::ostream& o;
     template<class X> alwaysenter& operator<<(X&& x) {
         o<<std::forward<X>(x);
         return *this;
     }
};
```

Comment: That's *not* the only thing you can do. You can always play around with the stream buffers. BTW you forgot to write the newline.

Comment: The stream buffer can't see individual insertions, but you could inherit from `std::basic_ostream` with a custom char_traits class, and specialize `std::basic_ostream::sentry` to enter a newline after each formatted insertion operation.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Downside is that the inheriting class won't have the same type as other streams with the same character type and different character traits. But it's a clever idea.

Comment: @Deduplicator Nope, I've done it several times myself using the `std::streambuf` interface.

Comment: @0x499602D2: And how did you handle stream-inserters calling other stream-inserters, possibly multiple times?

Comment: @Deduplicator The buffer was a thin wrapper around an `std::ostream&`. The inserters calling multiple other inserters couldn't possibly affect the behavior of the buffer. Are you thinking there's a danger for a circular function call cycle?

Comment: @0x499602D2: No, just that one written stream-intsertion can result in multiple sub-insertions, which (probably) should not each trigger a newline.